# Trouble with Google Play console notification: We have detected that your manifest file contains the permission REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions, google-play-console, policy

Hello i have an app in play console and receive the next notification:

**We have detected that your manifest file contains the permission  REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES.**

Google explain the steps for legalize it, but i don't have this permission in my manifest and I don't use functions to install files either ,i don´t know the real reason for this message and i'm afraid that my app will be removed from the store if I don't take the necessary measures.

Does anyone have more information on this or know what google might actually be detecting in my app?

This are the permissions in the manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"
        tools:node="remove" />
```

Edit: I receive a new mail from Google , they specify the permission belongs to HMS core, i search in the huawei developers and Huawei  release some update of all their libraries fixing or eliminating the permission from the code, it seem to solve the problem , i will upload a new version to play console hoping finishing the issue

Comment: I've had the same issue, but even the App Bundle Explorer says the permission is not included. It just randomly started prompting me to either include declaration or remove the permission. Honestly, support has become downright rude about it in their emails and there is no contacting a human for help. They recite the public FAQ and then tell you not to contact them unless it's with a different question. Play has become such a dumpster fire.

Comment: a week ago the warning appear again, it surprise me a lot; cheking in whole play console i find i was have an apk of a previuos version (with the permission) in a open test and in a close test, i have to upload a new version (without the permision) to this test and some ours later the problem was solve again. Please check this! @AbandonedCart

Comment: Policy -> App content -> Sensitive permissions and APIs -> Manage -> Request install packages permission -> View app bundles and APKs. Once again the issue was an inactive **unreviewed** internal testing build in the **paused** track from months ago. Those builds seem more thoroughly reviewed than the ones that are published. Dumpster fire.

Comment: make sure all apk that contains this permission were *inactive* in any track, you could check it in the App bundle explorer. Also ask support to provide which version code is invalid could be helpful. ( a full rollout is a must to make previous apk inactive )

Answer (score 2):

You are querying all packages with the package manager, this is no longer allowed since Android 8.0. If you don't see it in your manifest, you might want to check your merged manifest.

See more info here.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12085295?hl=en

Comment: Thank you for your answer , in fact the permission was in the merged manifest, was included for the hms services. Thank you again for your help